# Polynomial long division with extra brackets

Tags: polynom

the package polynom offers its style C, which is pretty close to my wishes, but not perfect:

I like to get the subtracted part in brackets with an leading minus like here:
[image: Polynomial long devision]

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=C,div=:,vars=x]{x^3-12x^2+5x+150}{x-5}

\end{document}
```

which leads to:
[image]

I would like to get the upper result.

Does anyone know, how to achive this?

Thanks in advance!